# Determining a Determinant given some scalar products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> We are given $x,y,z$ vectors in $\mathbb R^3$. We know that $x^Tx=3, y^Ty=3, z^Tz=3, x^Ty=2, y^Tz=2, z^Tx=1$. Furhermore we are given that
> for some matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$, we have $$Ax=y+z, Ay=x+z, Az=x+y$$ Determine whether the vectors $x,y,z$ are linearly
> dependant and compute the determinant of $A$.

I cannot manage to solve this, neither of the questions... Any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't your cube roots be cubes?

Comment: Yes you are right, am editing now!

Comment: How did you find the determinant?

Comment: Sorry this is wrong... I have not found the determinant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, multiply
$\alpha x^T+\beta y^T+\gamma z^T=0$
by $x$, $y$, and $z$ to obtain
$$\begin{align}
3\alpha+2\beta+\gamma &=0\\
2\alpha+3\beta+2\gamma &=0\\
\alpha+2\beta+3\gamma &=0\\
\end{align}.$$
Show that the only solution is $(0,0,0)$, hence $\{x,y,z\}$ is a basis.  (Notice that the coefficient matrix is the Gram-matrix of $x$, $y$, and $z$.)

The matrix of $A$ in respect to that basis is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now compute the determinant.